# Trying to load data to make graphs for soil water content and water salinity but can't load data

Tags: r

So I am trying load data to make graphs for soil water content and water salinity but can't the load data because I keep getting an error bar that says Error: cannot allocate vector of size 349 Kb I've tried to use memory.limit function but that didn't seem to work what should I do I am new to R any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
> memory.limit()
[1] 3498
> memory.limit(size=10497)
[1] 10497
> require(neonUtilities)
Loading required package: neonUtilities


> Swcws <- loadByProduct(dpID="DP1.00094.001",
+                            site=c("JORN"),
+                            startdate="2017-07", 
+                          enddate="2020-08")
Finding available files
  |===========================================================================| 100%

Continuing will download files totaling approximately 1.1 GiB. Do you want to proceed y/n: y
Downloading 38 files
  |===========================================================================| 100%

Unpacking zip files using 1 cores.
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed=01m 59s
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++| 100% elapsed=00s  
Stacking operation across a single core.
Stacking table SWS_1_minute
  |++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++          | 79% ~01m 02s      Error: cannot allocate vector of size 349 Kb
```

Comment: You are limited to the amount of memory available to your computer. The error message only indicates the last size requested, it doesn't tell you how much memory total R was requesting. How much RAM is in your computer?

Comment: Installed RAM: 4.00 GB(3.42 GB useable) Windows 10

Comment: That's not a lot, if the compressed data is ~1GB. Try a smaller date range. See if you can load a smaller subset of data.

Comment: Ok ill will try subsetting the data in half

Comment: So I tried splitting the years by half that didn't work then I tried the last four months of 2017 that didn't work then tried July 2017 - August 2018 that did work is there a way to stack all these data from all the date ranges together like i initially wanted together once I've loaded all the date range subsets together my goal is to have a graph for all 4 years and then have graphs for each year independently